# Raster Calculator in QGIS returning 'nan' values

Tags: raster, raster-calculator, qgis-2.6

I am attempting to add two rasters using the QGIS raster calculator and every output ends up as 'nan'. There were no problems with the raster calculator before trying to add these rasters, so I am stumped as to why it is not working with these rasters.

The code is:

```
"ForType@1" + "LandType@1"
```

Both rasters have the same projection and the pixel size are the same. It is a simple addition but any sort of calculation with these two rasters, whether addition or multiplication etc, ends up as no data.

Does anyone have suggestions as to why the raster calculator is not working? I am using QGIS 2.6.1, and other users have suggested updating the [version to 2.10](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154242/why-does-every-raster-calcuation-i-try-return-with-nan-values)

Comment: Try out `float("ForType@1" + "LandType@1")`.

Comment: Using float("ForType@1" + "LandType@1") results in -3.40282e+38 to -3.40282e+35

Comment: Sum each raster with it self: `("ForType@1" + "ForType@1")` and `("LandType@1" + "LandType@1")`. One of them probably have problems.

Comment: That method results in 'nan'. Both rasters show up okay, but do not work with the raster calculator

Comment: Well, I have the version 2.10 of QGIS and I don't have any problem. You decide then.

Comment: For reference, I got this error when I ran out of disk space when calculating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Copy Raster tool in ArcGIS was used to convert the Pixel Type of one raster (8 bit unsigned) so that it matched the Pixel Type of the other raster (32 bit unsigned).

The Raster Calculator then worked perfectly to add the two rasters together.