# Substract two raster image and add the information to polygons in Qgis

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a problem in Qgis. I have two elevation maps, both is raster. They are both DEM maps, one showing the topography without buildings, and one showing the topography with buildings. From these two DEM's I want to make a new DEM showing the height of the buildings.

[image: Image that shows the current data in Qgis]

I tried to use the raster calculator

[image]

But this just generates a layer where nothing is shown.

[image]

The new DEM should be used to add a new attribute to the polygons stating the mean elevation within each polygon, any help on that aspect as well?.

Comment: i see you have the dreaded 'NaN' raster. Does [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/154242/55203) help at all? (Are the rasters using the same projection?). Also, what do you see in the band statistics (layer properties > metadata > properties > band 1), are there any very extreme values?